# React: PureComponent and Component prototype

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Component:

```
function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}
```

PureComponent:

```
function ComponentDummy() {}
ComponentDummy.prototype = Component.prototype;

function PureComponent(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}

const pureComponentPrototype = (PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy());
pureComponentPrototype.constructor = PureComponent;
// Avoid an extra prototype jump for these methods.
Object.assign(pureComponentPrototype, Component.prototype);
pureComponentPrototype.isPureReactComponent = true;
```

I'm really comfused about the `ComponentDummy`. Why could't us use `pureComponent.prototype = {}`
Could someone explain what the codes below actually do???

```
const pureComponentPrototype = (PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy());
pureComponentPrototype.constructor = PureComponent;
```

I really appreciate if you can share me the prototype chain about `Component` `Dummy` and `PureComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Because If We use `PureComponent.prototype = new Component()`, the function Component will be called, and the props, context, and refs will also be created, which can be lead to take more storage.

But if we use `PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy()`, we can save that useless storage.

I thought.